# Where/How can I change my Object Inspector Colors in the Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-ide, object-inspector

I'd like to change the red and blue colors in my `Object Inspector` to different colors. The red and blue colors are really difficult to see and so I'd like to change it to something else, but I only want to change those two colors and nothing else.

This is my `Object Inspector` currently:

[image: Delphi Object Inspector]

The red on `Images`, `LiveBindings`, and `PopUpMenu` I'd like to change to something like a yellow color. The blue text on the property values I'd like to change to a lighter blue.

---

Is this possible? How/Where can I change the colors in my `Object Inspector`?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify all of the colors in `Options`.

In your main menu, Go to `Tools` > `Options` > `User Interface` > `Object Inspector`:

[image: Delphi Object Inspector Options]

---

You can choose a `SpeedSettings` Color Scheme:

[image: SpeedSettings]

Or manually click on a color name and set a custom color:

[image: Colors]

Comment: In Delphi 7: window menu _T̲ools > Environment O̲ptions > Object Inspector_"; the _S̲peedSettings_ even include "_Delphi 5 emulation_". See also [the official documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Object_Inspector_(Options)).